# CakePHP-AjaxMultiUpload and Auth

Tags: ajax, cakephp, authentication, upload

my problem is, that I used this plugin https://github.com/srs81/CakePHP-AjaxMultiUpload/ and everything worked correctly. But now I "installed" it again, in a new project, and I got a "failed"-message. The only thing which is different, compared to my old project, is, that I used the Auth-Component. Am I not able to use both at the same time?

Sorry for my english, but I'm from Germany :)

Thanks in advance!

My UploadController:

```
    <?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UploadController extends AppController { 

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow(array('add')); 
    }

    public function isAuthorized() {
         return true; 
    }

    public function add() {

    }

} ?>
```

my view:

```
<?php    
echo $this->Form->create('Upload', array('type' => 'file'));
    echo $this->Upload->edit('Upload', 'test');
    echo $this->Form->end();
    echo $this->Upload->view('Upload', 'test');
?>
```

Comment: have you foolowed this from the github page yet?                  Some Gotchas
Thanks to rscherf@github for the following two fixes.

Using Auth

If you are using Auth (either the CakePHP core Auth or some of the compatible or incompatible ones), you need to modify the controller to allow uploads to work.

Add these lines to the UploadsController.php (you may have to modify slightly depending on your Auth setup):

public function isAuthorized() {
    return true;
}

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow(array('upload','delete'));
}

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, but that doesn't solve the problem..

Comment: I was doubtful it would, sorry this is all I got I just started using cake earlier this week, Best of luck

Comment: Oh you were right, I wrote the two lines into the wrong controller.. Thank you :)

Comment: beautiful, glad you found an answer

Comment: @brendanmorrison rewrite your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The following is taken from the github gotchas section for the plugin (in the question) re-referenced here https://github.com/srs81/CakePHP-AjaxMultiUpload/

thanks to rscherf@github for the following two fixes.

Using Auth

If you are using Auth (either the CakePHP core Auth or some of the compatible or incompatible ones), you need to modify the controller to allow uploads to work.

Add these lines to the UploadsController.php (you may have to modify slightly depending on your Auth setup):

```
public function isAuthorized() {
    return true;
}

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow(array('upload','delete'));
}
```